# Animating DIV to Bottom of page and then on another click animate again to Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i was working on this div animation where the original position of div from top is 70% and the div is absolute.
Now, when I click on button it slides to bottom of page with top:95%.

Now I want to check if the position is top:95% and if so, then i want to slide it back to top:70%;

Somehow the Div slides to 95% but dosent come back. what i am doing wrong here??
code

css:-

```
  #mainMenu {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: black;
        top: 70%;
        position: absolute;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #clickToCheck {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
```

JQuery

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#mainMenu').click(function () {

            $("#mainMenu").animate({ top: "95%" }, 1100);

        });
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#clickToCheck').click(function () {
            if ($('#mainMenu').position().top === '95%') {
                $("#mainMenu").delay(1000).animate({ top: "70%" }, 1200);
            } else {
                alert('its not at bottom');
            }
        });
    });
```

and Html

```
<body>
<span id="clickToCheck">Click to CHeck</span>
<div id="mainMenu"></div>
```

Comment: You don't need two `$(document).ready` functions. Combine them into one function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function

```
$('#mainMenu').position().top
```

Will return the value in pixels instead of percentage. So if you want to check if the top is 95% you will have to do the math based on the top and window height (or div height). here is the code:

```
$('#mainMenu').position().top/$(window).height()*100
```

Here you will have the the percentage of the #mainMenu in relation to the full window. If the #mainMenu is inside a div, just do based on the div's height. Also beware that you will probably get a number like 94.2343123. So when checking, I would not do and "if = 95". I would do something like "if >= 93" or something like it.

Comment: Thanks man it's working, one more question, its displaying 94.99 not 95% , can you please show me how to fix it, thanks.

Comment: great solution, wish I had thought of that

Comment: I don't think you will always get 95% exactly, like I mentioned. One way to do is to round it up the result. Try Math.round($('#mainMenu').position().top/$(window).height()*100)

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that `.position()`, `.offset()`, and `.css()` all work in pixels by default.

A reasonable workaround would be to store the the menu's original [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and just check to see if its offset has changed, like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/59bFw/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mainMenu').data('startPos', $('#mainMenu').offset().top); // when the doc is ready store the original offset top.
    $('#mainMenu').click(function () {

        $("#mainMenu").animate({
            top: "95%"
        }, 1100);
    });

    $('#clickToCheck').click(function () {
        if ($('#mainMenu').offset().top > $('#mainMenu').data('startPos')) { // if new offset is greater than original offset 
            $("#mainMenu").delay(1000).animate({
                top: '70%'
            }, 1200);
        } else {
            alert('its not at bottom');
        }
    });
});
```